# Add CSS class to add-to-cart button, Woocommerce

Tags: plugins, css, woocommerce-offtopic

Im looking for a way to add a custom class to the add-to-cart button on the single-product.php page in Woocommerce. I have tried the following without any result:

1. Copy whole woocommerce-folder from the folder "plugins" to "themes/MY-THEME/woocommerce".
2. Modifying the file "add-to-cart.php" in "themes/MY-THEME/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button MY-TEST-CLASS-HERE' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Allthough I cant see the "MY-TEST-CLASS-HERE" in the source-code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

As explained in [their documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) WooCommerce provides a templating structure. Copying WC in your theme won't get you anywhere.

1. Create a `woocommerce` folder in your theme.
2. Copy any template inside the `templates` folder of WC inside your `woocommerce` theme folder. Beware you need to keep the structure from `templates` folder intact in your `woocommerce` theme folder for this to work.
3. Modify the templates in your theme's `woocommerce` folder to your liking. They have loading precendence over the ones inside plugin's `templates`.

Tip: do not copy all the templates from the plugin inside your theme! Only the ones you want to modify. From time to time WC updates their templates and adds functionality. WooCommerce will also let you know when a template you keep in your theme might have an upgraded version inside the plugin, after an upgrade.

And by the way, I suspect the downvote was not for the question itself, but for the title. I bet you know how to add a class to a button. What you didn't know was how to use the templating system of WooCommerce. Because you didn't google it, which I think you (technically) know how to do. Please, pardon my touch of sarcasm, it was either that or another downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found (a little hacky) is wrap the button in a span tag, add the class to the span and then in your css apply the properties to the button inheriting from the span:

```
<span class="my-nice-class">
    <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' ); ?>
</span>
```

and then in css:

```
.my-nice-class .button {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a child theme? If not, I would suggest that. Then you can custom style the button in the child theme's "style.css" file by editing the style of "add_to_cart_button" vs creating a new class

Comment: Pretty sure this refers to something else not to woocommerce buttons which is a plugin not a theme..